# How to export variable in ssh command

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this script with ssh sessions:

```
ssh -i /path/to/private_key somebody@ip_address_2 <<'EOF'
...
# Get the join command
JOIN_COMMAND=$(kubeadm token create --print-join-command)
EOF

ssh -i /path/to/second_private_key someother@ip_address_2 <<'EOF'
...
# run the JOIN_COMMAND
$JOIN_COMMAND
EOF
```

the second session needs to use the variable `JOIN_COMMAND` generated in the first session. I have tried using `export` in the first but wasn't exported, produced errors. How can I achieve this in bash?

Note: the ssh sessions happen on different remote nodes, i.e. two different ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

An environment variable is one that is passed from command to command when one executes another, it is something that is passed on, not something that sits in some ethereal place that any process can query.

Here it seems you want to use some form of permanent storage like the filesystem:

```
ssh -i /path/to/private_key somebody@ip_address sh << 'EOF' || exit
kubeadm token create --print-join-command > join-command
EOF
```

Which stores the output of `kubeadm` into a `join-command` file in `somebody`'s home directory.

And later:

```
ssh -i /path/to/private_key somebody@ip_address 'sh ./join-command'
```

Or if those two `ssh` commands are called from within the same local shell, have that shell store the command in one of its variables:

```
join_command=$(
  ssh -i /path/to/private_key somebody@ip_address sh <<'EOF'
# Get the join command
kubeadm token create --print-join-command
EOF
) || exit
```

```
printf '%s\n' "$join_command" |
  ssh -i /path/to/private_key somebody@ip_address sh
```

Here assuming the *command* that `kubeadm` outputs is actually code in the `sh` syntax.

Comment: These ssh sessions are happening on different ip addresses on the remote nodes though they both called from one script

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable on the current machine, not on the remote.

So something like

```
JOIN_COMMAND=$(ssh -i /path/to/private_key somebody@ip_address_2 kubeadm token create --print-join-command)
```

Note you don't need the "here" scripts for something this simple.

Similarly (if there's no special characters) you may then be able to do

```
ssh -i /path/to/second_private_key someother@ip_address_2 $JOIN_COMMAND
```